# Trying to order the results of includes in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an activerecord model that is joined to another model multiple times:

```
class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :treated_by, foreign_key: :treated_by_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :person_involved, foreign_key: :person_involved_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :case_manager, foreign_key: :case_manager_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

At some points I wish to grab the Claims and all their User instances so I avoid N+1 queries by using includes:

```
claims = Claim.all.includes(:user, :treated_by, :person_involved)
```

That goes great but now I want to sort the claims (without them being in memory) so I would like to do something like:

```
Claim.all.includes(:user, :person_involved, :treated_by).order('treated_by.last_name')
```

But I get invalid SQL unless I user the table name like this:

```
Claim.all.includes(:user, :person_involved, :treated_by).order('users.last_name')
```

Which clearly won't help me order by the treated by subset of users last_name for instance.  How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Abishek Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5213979/abhishek-kumar) mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40169606/746882), you should probably use `joins` instead of `includes`, since `includes` is only there to prevent the N+1 query problem. It *does* seem to allow you to sort by association as well, but it will not help you if your associations have custom names.

I think you will have to step a little bit outside of ActiveRecord's nice and cozy place for a while, and write the join statement manually:

```
Claim.all
  .joins("INNER JOIN users AS treated_bys ON claims.treated_by_id = treated_bys.id")
  .order("treated_bys.last_name ASC")
```

...then you can spinkle the query with `includes` statements as well, if you need that to avoid N+1 queries, etc.

Comment: Good answer! Just wanted to mention that `INNER JOIN users AS treated_bys ON ...` will limit `claims` collection only to those which have `treated_by` associated value. Claims without `treated_by` will not be fetched from Database. May be it would be safer to use LEFT JOIN instead. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: Thank you for that clarification @Semjon

Answer (score 2):

As has been said by other people here `order('treated_by.last_name')` doesn´t work because `treated_by` is an alias working only in rails but is not included in the SQL statement to execute. `order('users.last_name')` does not fail but is not the result expected, you need the alias asigned automatically by rails which could be... I don't know, ¿`t1`?

By the way, that is not the "Rails way" to do it. When you add a `belongs_to` relation to your model you can add a scope when you can specify restriction for the `ON` statement every time you join throught this relation and how to sort by its columns: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

```
class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :treated_by, foreign_key: :treated_by_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :person_involved, foreign_key: :person_involved_id, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :case_manager, foreign_key: :case_manager_id, class_name: 'User'

  belongs_to :treated_and_sort_by, -> { order last_name: :asc }, foreign_key: :treated_by_id, class_name: 'User'
end
```

So this should work like this...

```
Claim.all.includes(:user, :person_involved, :treated_and_sort_by)
```

Answer (score 1):

`includes` here preloads the relations using separate queries and hence it is not possible to order it according to other table's column.

You should use `joins` instead.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, but just using `joins` instead of `includes` will not solve the problem of having to refer to a specific association for sorting. I think this approach will have to be combined with writing the join manually.

Comment: I don't see a need to write join manually, which version of rails are you on?

Comment: I think you are missing a vital point in the original question, namely that OP is asking for how to sort on a column of a specific association that _does not have the same table name as the association_ because the original model has multiple associations to the User model. Therefore, just ordering by `users.last_name` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here, table name in query should be plural.
Try with following :

```
Claim.all.includes(:user, :person_involved, treated_by).order('treated_bys.last_name')
```

Happy Coding !!

Comment: Sorry Shefalee but as there is only one model User which uses the users table there is no treated_bys table.  I need to scope the order by clause to the subset of Users which have are dragged in through the treated_by join.

Comment: So, here treated_by is not table . Then treated_by is? @robertpostill

Comment: Shefalee, treated_by is a belongs_to relationship on Claim (as per the class definition near the top of the question).  It points to the users table (as do the others) so effectively it's a User.

Answer (score 0):

```
Claim.all.includes(:user, :person_involved, treated_by).sort_by { |c| c.treated_by.last_name }
```

Comment: Dinesh, this ends up being an in-memory sort on the result set right?  I was hoping for something that would modify the query sent to the DB so I could then paginate or further scope it.

Comment: @robertpostill Yes it is in memory sort.

Comment: @robertpostill Can you try `Claim.joins(:treated_by).order('users.last_name').includes(:user, :person_involved)`. You will not be able to preload treated_by users but I guess you will be able to order records by  them.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: **This does not work. Don't try this.**

Would this work?

```
Claim.all
  .includes(:user, :person_involved, :treated_by)
  .order(treated_by: { last_name: :asc})
```

I know ActiveRecord accepts that syntax for joins, but I'm unsure if it works for sorting.

---

Update: ActiveRecord does not support this syntax for ordering records. The `order` method accepts either a string or a hash. When it gets a hash, it expects the key(s) to be columns and the value(s) to be directions (one of `:asc, :desc; :ASC, :DESC`, "asc", "desc", "ASC", "DESC"`). It seems like it does not support nested hashes, like it does in`where` clauses.